# Cutting out a cylinder of maximum possibe size from a cube

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

A cylinder of maximum possible size is cut out from a solid wooden cube. How much material is lost in the process?

What I could think is as follows:

Suppose the cube is of a side $a,$ so the volume is $a^3$.
However that cylinder cut out from it must be having a height of $a$ but what about the radius?

Comment: Why must the height be $a?$  Why couldn't the axis of the cylinder be a diagonal of the cube, for instance?  Not saying it is, just that possibilities like this need to be considered.

Comment: I mean, if you have already decided that the height should be $a$ (i.e. the axis of the cylinder is parallel to an edge of the cube), then the maximum radius would be $a/2$